# Get multiple div selection value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying record in two column . I need to perform common operation (e.g. delete)
based on selection of div. if user select div ids **participant_1, participant_4,
participant_6** at a time then I need to get these three ids. Is there any way to achieve this in JQuery. if user selected three ids together then i want delete it `in one time not one by one`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <div class="left_column">
        <div class="record_row" id="participant_1"> 
        ----
        ----
        </div>
        <div class="record_row" id="participant_3"> 
        ----
        ----
        </div>
        <div class="record_row" id="participant_5"> 
        ----
        ----
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_column">
        <div class="record_row" id="participant_2"> 
        ----
        ----
        </div>
        <div class="record_row" id="participant_4"> 
        ----
        ----
        </div>
        <div class="record_row" id="participant_6"> 
        ----
        ----
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try out jQuery UI's "selectable" http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution of your problem :-

```
 $('.record_row').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');  
 });
```

I have added button to get all ids

```
 var ids = new Array();
    $('#btn').click(function () {

    var selected_activities =$('.selected');
    var ids = new Array();
    selected_activities.each(function(){
          var id_str   =  $(this).attr("id");
          var id_arr      =  id_str.split("_");
          var selval       =  id_arr[1];
        if(selval!='undefined' && selval!='' && selval!=null){
            ids.push(selval);
        }
    });
    alert(ids);
});
```

See demo here [Live Demo Code](http://jsfiddle.net/zDvMW/20/)

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the click event with class selector and use this.id to get the current element it. `this` is the source object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Yvcnn/3/)**

```
 $('.record_row').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');  
 });

$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('.selected').each(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: If I select three div then it will give me three ids?

Comment: I have already checked this but unable to find multiple selection div ids. It only select one div at a time

Answer (score 0):

> if user selected three ids together then i want delete it in one time not one by one

Yes, Add a class `selected`:

```
var css_class = '.record_row';
$(css_class).click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    if ($('.selected').length == 3) 
      // delete 

    // to get all three ids
    var listID = $.map($('.selected'), function(elem){ return $(elem).attr('id') });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Either you bind the `onclick` event to each div

```
<div class="record_row" id="participant_1" onclick="doyoursutff(this.id);">
```

or you can bind the event as

```
$('.left_column').find('div').click(function(){
do your stuff...
})

$('.right_column').find('div').click(function(){
    do your stuff...
    })
```

or simply do this

```
$('.record_row').click(function(){
           do your stuff here ...
})
```

Comment: How to get ids whether two div selected on three. I want these ids when I perform any operation based on multiple div id selection.

Comment: You can hold div ids in a seperate variable when clicking on the div. Try to use click event for individual div and hold there ids. After getting ids do your stuff (delete)